# What is the difference between Safari and iOS Safari on caniuse.com?

Tags: ios, browser, safari, browser-support

Sometimes i check browser support features on [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/) website. Now i looked at [touch events](http://caniuse.com/#feat=touch) compatibility and realised that iOS Safari support this feature, but Safari doesn't. What is the difference between Safari and iOS Safari on caniuse.com? As far as i know Safari browser is tied to the iOS and is not supported on Windows/Linux, so it should point to same browser. Maybe it's divided to mobile and desktop versions? I couldn't find any answer on their website and on other sites as well.

I enclose an image as well (support may change in the future):

[image: Can I Use browsers support table]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Safari refers to desktop Safari on a Mac, whereas iOS Safari is Safari on an iOS device.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just found out on Macs we have macOS, not iOS.

Comment: Im looking for answer why Safari is not identical on iOS and Mac OS? I have latest iOS and latest Mac OS and some CSS thinkg shows differently. Mac OS user agent `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.3 Safari/605.1.15` and iOS user agent `Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.3 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1`. The same version 14.0.3 but it is not identical browser bacuse I see on my website differences. E.g. on Safari Mac OS does not work "overflow: overlay".